# Android OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, adapter, listactivity

I have a ListActivity with an Adapter attached. Now I want to register a click on a list item in the adapter. This is my solution in onCreate of the ListActivity:

```
        this.myList = getListView();
        this.myList.setAdapter(this.adapter);
        this.myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                Log.d("Click", "ListView");
            }
        });
```

But the OnItemClickListener never responds.
What is wrong?

Comment: make sure you have imported `import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;`

Answer (score 1):

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

 MobileArrayAdapter adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);       

 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
 //your data

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set `OnItemClickListener`. You have to override `onListItemClick`:

```
@Override 
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something when a list item is clicked
    }
```

The third parameter, `position`, is the element at `position` in your adapter.

Answer (score -1):

If u have row layout for each list item which u have used in adpter than in that row layout for each ImageView or Button or Checkbox or TextView etc ... u have to add this line in xml

```
 android:clikable="false"
 android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing this:

```
    this.myList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

By default, list doesnot have any choice mode i.e. its set as CHOICE_MODE_NONE by default. So to make it clickable, we have to set it as CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE or CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE as per you want .